# How do $_REQUEST two fields and post them together on another page?

Tags: mysql, request

I have a form that inserts data into mySQL.  It works fine.

After the submission, I have a success page that displays 'part_no'.  I need to also show 'add_qty', as well.

How do i alter my post script to show two field data's on the success page?

Here is part of my code (that already works):

```
$part_no = $_REQUEST['part_no'] ;

header("location: inv_fc_add_success.php?part_no=" . urlencode($part_no));
}
else {
header("location: inv_fc_add_fail.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 3 things.

First, you'll need:

```
$add_qty = $_REQUEST['add_qty'];
```

Alternatively you can simply use `$_REQUEST['add_qty']` directly instead of assigning it to a new variable (`$add_qty`).

Then instead of:

```
header("location: inv_fc_add_success.php?part_no=" . urlencode($part_no));
```

you need:

```
header("location: inv_fc_add_success.php?part_no=" . urlencode($part_no) . "&add_qty=" . urlencode($add_qty));
```

Then, on the page inv_fc_add_success.php (which you will need to edit), you display the variable the same way that you display $part_no. As always, you can either assign it to a variable, like you already do at the top, or you can just use `$_REQUEST['add_qty']` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Just append it as another $_GET variable i.e `part_no="part"&quantity=1`

```
header("location: inv_fc_add_success.php?part_no=" . urlencode($part_no)."&qty=".$quantity );
```

Comment: Is this correct:  header("location: inv_fc_add_success.php?part_no=" . urlencode($part_no)."&add_qty=".$add_qty );

Comment: Looks ok. You should do a var_dump on your $_GET or $_REQUEST array in the inv_fc_add_success.php script to make sure they are passed in correctly.